# def or val or lazy val for grammar rules?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I know the difference between `def` and `val` and `lazy val` in general, but I'm not sure about their repercussions when it comes to Parser Combinators. All examples I have seen contain code like this:

```
def statement: Parser[Statement] =
  ifStatement |
  whileStatement |
  expressionStatement | ...
```

From a few experiments I have done, it seems `val` and `lazy val` work as well, but I'm not sure if there are cases where they wouldn't work anymore, like recursion or positioned parsers or whatnot.

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the api documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers), the parser-building methods and operators are implemented using by-name parameters which are then [cached using `lazy val`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L272).

That being said, you still have to be careful about order of initialization. The following code will result in a null reference exception:

```
val as = a.*
val a = "a"
```

However the following is fine (because the argument to `~` is by-name):

```
val as = "a" ~ a.*
val a = "a"
```

Putting `lazy` in front of everything will 'help', but is noisy. Performance should not be a big deal, as generally you will only want to initialize the grammar once. `def` expressions will be initialized once for each point they are referenced.

You can be a bit clever and eliminate plumbing for your 'minor' productions using block syntax:

```
lazy val addExpr = {
  val add = expr ~ "+" ~ expr
  val sub = expr ~ "-" ~ expr
  add | sub
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I can just use `def` everywhere and do not have to worry too much about performance?

Comment: In essence, but you should take care that your grammar is not being re-initialized every time you use it. There are also implications with regards to memoization when using [packrat parsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers) as the notion of parser identity becomes important, but I would not worry about it unless performance becomes an issue.